# How to implement binary (b) variables in snmp4j

Tags: java, snmp, snmp4j

I am trying to port an snmpset command to snmp4j but am getting a error code 5 generic error which doesn't tell me much. The variable type is b (binary). I looked at the end all of examples the SnmpRequest.java source and found that b arguments are converted to an OctetString as follows:

```
 case 'b':
     variable = OctetString.fromString(value, ' ', 2);
```

When I toString the variable I get the following for values of "0" and "1" respectively: 00, 01

when I set the OID from the  command line it echos back 80 and 40.

```
jgaer@ljgaer2_~: snmpset -t 60 192.168.60.105 cwNetStgSvrWriteEnable.0 b 0
CW-NET-STG-SVR-MIB::cwNetStgSvrWriteEnable.0 = BITS: 80 hwWriteEn(0) 
jgaer@ljgaer2_~: snmpset -t 60 192.168.60.105 cwNetStgSvrWriteEnable.0 b 1
CW-NET-STG-SVR-MIB::cwNetStgSvrWriteEnable.0 = BITS: 40 fsWriteEn(1)
```

If I do a get on the OID in snmp4j and toString the variableBindings in the response event I see the following when the OID is set to 0 and 1 respectively:

```
 [1.3.6.1.4.1.27675.20.1.6.0 = 80]
 [1.3.6.1.4.1.27675.20.1.6.0 = c0]
```

When I run the following snippet of code with a value of "1" I get the Generic error.

```
    Object result = null;
    PDU pdu = new ScopedPDU();
    pdu.add(new VariableBinding(new OID("1.3.6.1.4.1.27675.20.1.6.0"), OctetString.fromString("1", ' ', 2)));
    pdu.setType(PDU.SET);
    ResponseEvent event = snmp.send(pdu, userTarget);
    if (event != null) {
        pdu = event.getResponse();
        if (pdu.getErrorStatus() == PDU.noError) {
            LOG.debug("SNMPv3 SET Successful for " + oid + " ObjectType " + pdu.get(0).getVariable().getClass() + " value " +
                    pdu.get(0).getVariable() + ":" + pdu.getVariableBindings());
            result = pdu.get(0).getVariable();
        } else {
           LOG.debug("SNMPv3 SET Unsuccessful. Error Code " + pdu.getErrorStatus() + " " + pdu.getErrorStatusText());
        }
    } else {
        LOG.debug("SNMP send unsuccessful.");
    }
    return result;

 output

SNMPv3 SET Unsuccessful. Error Code 5 General variable binding error
```

If I run it with a value of "0" it runs without error and the object gets updated on the remote agent but the variable value returned is 00 not 80.

```
[1.3.6.1.4.1.27675.20.1.6.0 = 00]
```

I am thoroughly confused about the returned values of 80 and C0. I haven't figured out how to create the OctestString for a binary 1.

Answer (score 0):

Repeating the set using the values of xC0 (11000000) and x80 (10000000) instead of 1 and 0 worked. In the MIB .txt file it indicated that it was the MSB that got set. Thats not quite the MSB, that is always 1. Somehow snmpset understands the distinction and knows to interpret 0 and 1 as x80 and xC0, I am guessing that there is something in either the .cds or .cmi file that snmpset must understand. Assuming I could just cut and paste from snmpRequest.java was a mistake. Still learning snmp.